# Paperclip saving portrait Iphone images in landscape mode. Messing up cropping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image-processing, paperclip, jcrop

S - it doesn't work when the image is I am using jcrop and paperclip to crop images. This works fine when the iphone image that is saved is in landscape mode or when the portrait image is not from an iphone , however , it does not work when the image is in portrait mode because the portrait image is saved as if it is in landscape mode. The original image that is saved appears in landscape , but all of the other styles that I define for that image - large, medium ,etc appear in portrait which is great!.  When I crop I can have different math that crops the original image based on whether it is in landscape mode or portrait mode. That seems tedious. Is there a paperclip solution out there? Am I doing something wrong when the original portrait images are saved as landscape?